# Flutter: What best practice to using bloc

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am refactoring a flutter project that every single page/screen uses many streams components in one bloc!

So, for example, all the streams on the home page are with the home bloc.

Which causes many problems

1. performance as all those streams will load at once ( all of the streams are SQLite queries )
2. not very easy to maintain or debug.

So I'm thinking of creating a bloc/cubit for each page component that has its own state, but that will lead to a lot of boilerplate for a single screen!.

I don't know what the best practice is here using bloc! specially folder structure after this do we move those blocs to screen folder like `lib/screens/home/blocs/some_bloc` or let it as it's now like `lib/blocs/some_bloc`

there's no code here to implement I guess as the question is about the best practice to my use case!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first, each project has its own cases, and depending on them there is better or worse architecture to use.

I've had the same structure you are describing in one of my applications, so I will tell you my point of view on this.

First, go ahead and create a bloc for each page component since they are different, and don't worry about boilerplates cause most probably you will use those blocs elsewhere in your app rather than the home screen.

In my case, I had CategoryBloc, OffersBloc, BrandBloc, and AdsBloc all integrated with the home screen, but most of them have their usage in other places of the app, plus you will be following the Single Responsibility Principle

Second, regarding the folder structure, it's really up to the app scenarios and cases and which one you would be more comfortable using, some prefer `lib/feature_a/blocs/` and some prefer `lib/blocs/`, the second one would be better if you use the same bloc in multiple features.

```
lib
  |
  |=> blocs
  |       |=> bloc_a
  |       |=> bloc_b
  |=> screens
          |=> screen_a   (using bloc_a)
          |=> screen_b   (using bloc_a and bloc_b)
```

but again this is a point of view and there might be better solutions that I don't know